# Can I level a floor with joint compound?

Tags: flooring, self-leveling-concrete, drywall-mud, leveling

I am working on a house that has been lifted 7 feet in the air. What it looks like is that they leveled the out side perimeter but when they put the post in the middle of the house they didn't check the floor for level because I have highs and low  spots all over the house.

I put some plywood down to raise some of the low spots and tried to blend it all in with leveling compound. Well I've used all the compound I have and have gotten kind of close. So now I'm putting in the flooring. I've noticed I have a few low spots still.

Can I put Sheetrock mud under the flooring to help level it out?

Comment: You're already familiar with Henry 547 and Henry 549, for instance, but you're looking to save a buck or use on-hand material?

Comment: How big are the humps/dips? What are you putting down on the floor? If you're putting down carpet, it _might_ be level _enough_. If you're putting down tile, the thinset might be sufficient to bridge small gaps. If you're putting down some sort of engineered flooring, you will need to be level within tolerances of the product you're using. It would be helpful to [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

> can I put sheetrock mud under the flooring to help level it out

Naw, it doesn't set hard enough. However, you could use a hard-setting type plaster, like Durham's Water Putty or Fix-It-All.